# What should I do when I am Not getting paid on time as a contractor

Tags: salary, united-kingdom, contractors

I have started a work as a contractor in a renowned firm 2 months ago. Almost Everyone on my team is a contractor.

I have to submit an approved timesheet (by my manager) to my umbrella company, which in turn sends an invoice to the company I work for to get me paid.

This company has a "rule" that on the day the get the invoice, the will start the payroll and I will receive it in 30 days.

For my First month, I waited for 30 days from the date of invoice submission, and still not received the pay. And the second month will of course be paid more later.

I talked to my fellow contractors, and they say that they get paid maximum in a week's time.

I am confused as to what should I do. I do not want to discontinue my work, as I like it, and also I will be getting paid less if I skip days.

I have escalated the issue to my manager. But there is no strict action being taken until now.

please suggest how I should proceed, without jeopardising my relations with the manager.

Comment: escalate it officially or leave bills are important to pay...if you do this to any organization i.e banks or any they charge you interest as fine...i dont know how come employers are exception to this golden rule...

Comment: As I have mentioned, I have already escalated the issue. Which did not help much.

Comment: I would consult my contract. And if that doesn't help, perhaps you should consult an attorney?

Comment: if there is a non-payment clause in your contract you can (threaten to) just up and leave and find better ground

Answer (score 13):

Tell your manager, "I cannot work without being paid.  I have responsibilities to meet.  Who should *WE* speak with, today, to get this resolved?"  Sit at his desk until he acts.  If he tells you to go do your work, repeat the above sentence.

If something is wrong, it is his responsibility to deal with it.  If he will not deal with it, politely excuse yourself, and go talk to an attorney.  Do not do any more work until this is resolved.

I got burned for over $30K being the "nice guy" about this very issue.  NEVER AGAIN.

Comment: were u not paid those $30k ever? Why din't u sue them?

Comment: Because they filed for bankruptcy.  Welcome to contracting, otherwise known as "Unsecured Creditor #8."

Answer (score 9):

The relationship is between your umbrella company and the company you should be escalating to the accounts department not your manager.

I would get the Umbrella company to send a formal overdue notice to the accounts department - demanding payment as a mater of urgency - and imply that you will pursue this through the courts.

Umbrella companies normally invoice weekly and you should get paid weekly in arrears.