# Haven't been paid for last month, is it ok to stop working?

Tags: salary, email, startup

I'm working as the lead and currently (since everyone else was laid off for money reasons) sole developer of a start-up, and have been there since its beginning a couple of years ago.

A self-employed friend of mine also does work for the company every now and then, but stopped completely—temporarily—as he hasn't been paid since last summer for his work.

For the past couple of months pay has been a couple of days late because of money problems, but this month (after being warned that it would be a couple of days late) I still haven't been paid over two weeks later. I'm working abroad right now so emailed my boss, and he explained that he's waiting for some money to come in and he'll pay me ASAP—the same thing he's told my colleague for months.

I trust the guy, and I know he'll pay me when he can, but the thing is my colleague hasn't been paid for months, and unlike him I don't have any savings, though I'll be returning to university after the summer anyway to finish the last year of my degree, and was due to start working less hours as I used to for the same company.

What I'm here to ask is, is it okay to just stop working until I'm paid? The company depends entirely on me, there's a lot of work to do and things would come to a standstill if I stop working, so I don't really want to do it. But I feel very uncomfortable working without having been paid, especially that it's now closer to the next paycheck (and rent coming out of my account!) than the previous.

How should I word the email when I explain that I won't work for free? Should I give him notice (a few days, or more?) or just stop working immediately? I've already made it clear I'm unhappy about the situation, but just got excuses.

If I didn't have so much invested in this company (emotionally) I would simply quit, but doing this isn't as easy as just leaving.

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/410/what-should-we-do-with-questions-about-personal-dilemmas-with-no-right-answer

Comment: Not only is it OK for you to stop working, it's OK for you to not even start working again until they pay you up front.

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17161/what-should-i-do-when-i-am-not-getting-paid-on-time-as-a-contractor/17195#17195 - Hopefully that's useful.

Comment: `I trust the guy, and I know he'll pay me when he can...` So will he skip his mortgage/rent payment and pay you instead?

Comment: "I trust the guy, and I know he'll pay me when he can" - you should prepare yourself to never see a dime of that money, and to lose a friend.  He's delusional, and you may be as well.

Comment: Fair enough. You make good points. I guess what I meant was that I trust he never intended to put me in this situation. But it is what it is now, and you're right - he may never be able to pay me, so I won't risk more time with the company until I can be sure.

Comment: +1 I like this question, very ontopic ;) . Please let us know what your final decision is and how you resolved this situation, it may be relevant for future readers ;) .

Comment: @SharkofMirkwood - Good intentions are like opinions....there is more to that saying but I won't repeat it.  There is no excuse for not paying your staff, I guarantee you, his bills are being paid.

Comment: With careful manipulation, someone might be able to work another week and get paid for the previous month so as to be giving up three weeks of unpaid work when you left instead of six weeks.  Approach the boss and tell them that your financial situation is dire and that you need to be paid within a week or you will have to leave.  Imply that if you get paid you will remain on the job.  If you get paid, cash the check and leave the day that you are paid.  If not, leave after one week.  In other words, it's worth it to risk one more week of unpaid work in order to possibly collect a month's pay.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's a harsh reality here: this company has failed.  There's a tiny chance it can be be brought back to life, but not by anything you, as a lone and remote developer, can do.

This is probably very difficult for the founder. It's probably disappointing for you, but not a disaster.  When you write it up for your resume, be sure to explain what you did for them. Think through clearly what you learned from this experience: you'll be asked about that in future job interviews. "If you had it to do over, what might you do differently?" is a standard kind of question. This is real-life experience, not just some tech buzzword, and makes your candidacy for your next job quite a bit stronger.

As far as letting the founder know what's going on, you don't need to burn your bridges. You can remind him that you're returning to school. "I need to earn some money for school fees so I'm spending some time on another project" will explain your situation perfectly.

If he comes back and says, "wait, wait, work for me" then you can say, "I AM working for you, but I still need to do the other project to earn money."  This makes it clear to him that you have to get on with your life and meet your own needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer - I got a few good answers and they all made me realise I wouldn't be doing anything wrong by taking time out from the job, but yours really reminded me that they have no right to make me feel bad about that. I think I'll be leaving the company temporarily and looking for some contract work before going back to my studies, and one way or another by then I'll know where things stand! Also, thanks for the pointers about future interviews. I'll definitely have to keep that in mind.

Comment: @SharkofMirkwood - Unless everyone who is owed money is paid.  You really should not return to this company.  Companies that don't pay their employees have a history of returning to the same behavior.  Your responsability to work for the company ended when the company didn't pay you for your work.

Answer (score 12):

The business transaction is that you get paid in return for work performed. Conversely, no money, no work. No matter how progressive the company culture and no matter how good the bosses, at the end of the day, you have to be paid. Your landlord only cares about the rent and couldn't care less why you can't pay it. The supermarket clerks are similarly sympathetic.

I am happy that your boss is a good guy, but it doesn't matter why he can't pay you. He has to pay you. Period. Disclosure: I did not follow my own advice and stuck with my boss when the firm lost a customer who accounted for 90% of its revenues. That was years ago. I worked for six months without pay and fortunately, before my savings ran out, the firm stopped its nose dive. I did it because I liked the better angels of his nature :) I would have been better off collecting unemployment, helping him to the best of my ability and getting another job that paid real money - I am not doing that again. As a final note, I never recovered my lost salary. You have to look out for yourself because you can't rely on anyone else.

Forget about equity. Any equity they give you at this point is worth little more than toilet paper. You can't eat equity and you can't pay rent or mortgage with  equity. Equity is worth something only if it's convertible to cash. They are most probably going down the tubes at this point. Make sure they don't take you with them.

My advice to you is to look for another job ASAP, because you are at severe financial risk. If you want to help them, take care of yourself first and give them all the help you want to give them - after hours. If you can't help yourself, you are in no position to help anyone.

In your email, give them say a week's notice, tell them that your are on a precarious financial footing, that you need all the time available to get another job. Tell them that you'd love to continue working for them but the bottom line is that you can't afford to work for free. Tell them it's been good to work with them and that they treated you well, that you are sorry that you are compelled to go, that you wish them the best of luck, and that you'll help them however you can. Apply for unemployment benefits ASAP - if the firm contests the benefits, simply tell the unemployment office that you haven't been paid.

> Follow-up comment from @JimG "Any equity they give you at this point is worth little more than toilet paper. That assumes that the equity shares are printed on paper. Otherwise, I disagree. Toilet paper has more utility"

Comment: `Any equity they give you at this point is worth little more than toilet paper.` That assumes that the equity shares are printed on paper. Otherwise, I disagree. Toilet paper has more utility.

Comment: @JimG I incorporated your comment into my answer, with full attribution to you, of course :)

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan thanks for the great answer. I chose to accept another one as it made it easier for me to go through with my choice, but upvoted yours nonetheless. I was considering equity, but yeah it doesn't seem like it's worth the hassle and risk. I'm better off finding work elsewhere, at least temporarily, and returning to work here if and when they've paid me in full.

Comment: @SharkofMirkwood - Even if they pay you.  Make sure the company pays everyone else.  Ask for a business plan, ask for income statements, ask for the records that show how much money will come in and will go out.

Comment: @Ramhound Your demands are loony. The OP is not an investor in the company.Making sure that the company pays everyone else is none of your business. If the company is not paying the OP the money it owes the OP, that's it. I it pays the OP the money it wes the OP but can't meets his first paychecj, that's it. It's that simple.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan - He hasn't been paid in 2 weeks. I think its a fair request if you have not paid me in 2 weeks to show those things.  But I don't work for companies that don't pay me.

Answer (score 7):

> What I'm here to ask is, is it okay to just stop working until I'm
>   paid? The company depends entirely on me, there's a lot of work to do
>   and things would come to a standstill if I stop working, so I don't
>   really want to do it.

Reading this is quite painful to me. A lot of computer work is invisible so even on a team we invest tons of heart and soul on simple things. But at the end of the day work you do not own yourself—and do for others—is truly just work.

Here is the harsh reality: If they haven’t paid you yet, the chances of them paying you are slim to none. If you have a contract that stipulates pay, you might be able to legally leverage that in some way if things truly go south. But the reality is that even if you do—sorry to say—take the employers to court for back pay, you might only get a fraction back of what you are rightfully owed.

Chances are if the company is failing, they will claim bankruptcy and there you go. 100% of nothing. Maybe the court would order them to—I don’t know—sell the chairs and coffee machine to pay back vendors. But then you are the end of a huge list of people owed. Meaning when you get something it might be so low it’s a joke and the check is best framed on the wall as such.

Some might suggest equity, but I can show you tons of examples of that not working either for the same reason. Basically if you are not getting paid, the chances of equity are zilch.

> If I didn't have so much invested in this company (emotionally) I
>   would simply quit, but doing this isn't as easy as just leaving.

Well, The choice is yours:

- What is the company to you? A paycheck? A career? A stepping stone?
- If you leave & they fall apart how would it impact you? Would you be seen as the reason for the collapse or someone acting reasonably in an unreasonable scenario.
- What exactly are you doing there that you can do similarly elsewhere? Meaning if you are a coder, what code and processes have you created that can be transported somewhere else. And I do not mean code per se, but mainly ideas, concepts and the things that make you valuable.

It’s taken me a long time to truly realize my heart and soul can only exist for my own projects. And if my own projects dovetail with my employers, all the better. But at the end of the day, they own your work and you own yourself.

Comment: "you are the end of a huge list of people owed." -- That's not true: unpaid employees are first in line in bankruptcy proceedings. But this questioner might be a contractor.

Comment: no doubt there won't be much money left and you'll get a few cents on the dollar if you're lucky. But in the US unpaid employees are first in line among unsecured creditors.

Comment: I'm not deluding myself. Having been through this, I know that actual bankruptcy deals REALLY don't like unpaid employees; it's sometimes a criminal matter and the lawyers and financiers scramble to fix it. But, of course, many failing companies don't have enough left to bother with bankruptcy. In that case there's no recourse.

Comment: @OllieJones It doesn't matter that former employees are first in line if there is no money to be had from bankruptcy proceedings. And it's not as if that money is coming in a timely way.

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for the answer, I did consider asking for equity and I guess it doesn't seem out of the question for things to improve soon for the company, but it's definitely not worth the risk for me right now. I've decided to cut my losses for now but I'll make it clear that I'm happy to start working again once I've been paid.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a textbook example for where you should ask for equity in the company in exchange for a specified amount of work. They don't have cash to pay you, but it seems like your work is vital. This is great bargaining position for you, and it actually would be a win-win-situation for everyone involved. They would get your work without you hitting their cash flow.

After all, it sounds like your choices are:

1. Continue working and *hoping* for a paycheck
2. Drop everything and walk off
3. Ask for equity and continue working

Of course, this only makes sense if you trust the cash flow problems to be temporary and the company to make a profit some day. It you don't have that level of trust any more, I would suggest cutting your losses.

*If* you decide to cut your losses, be professional about it. You will likely meet your current boss and colleagues again. Then again, I don't think they will bear a grudge against you if you explain that you simply can't keep working without getting paid.

Comment: If they're not meeting payroll, equity likely isn't worth anything either. :)

Comment: You can't pay rent with equity.  You can't pay for food with equity.  If he cannot even pay an employee after 3 months the equity isn't worth anything.

Comment: Somebody on another question pointed out that if a company is not paying its employees, then they've probably stiffed their suppliers, as well.  The company is likely very, very deep in the hole.